# Movies rating trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I would like to create a trigger that average rating movies. I have tried to create a trigger but when I'm adding new data for rating, I get an error from the trigger

> ORA-04091: table RATING is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

I have searched for solutions for that problem because using `select` in the trigger. But I don't know how I should change my code, is there any solution for this case?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AvgRate_trig
AFTER INSERT ON Rating
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TB_MOVIES 
    SET AvgRating = (SELECT AVG(RATE) FROM RATING 
                     WHERE tb_movies.movieid = rating.movieid)
    WHERE movieid = new.movieid;
END
```

Comment: Your design is flawed.  You should not be trying to store the 'average'.  One of the fundamental rules of data design is 'do not store that which can be computed'.  While we can only guess at your actual design, it appears you have individual ratings in a table called RATING.  So when you need to know the 'average', compute it at run time.   If you try to store the ever-changing average, it is only a matter of time before the 'stored' value becomes out of sync with the actual value.

Comment: so, for averaging data what is the best thing should i do? do i have to code manualy outside database, and averaging the rating and store the rating to database? sorry for bad english.

Comment: The best thing to do?  Do you see that SELECT statement in your trigger?  Not the UPDATE, but just the SELECT.  And what is that SELECT doing?  It is calculating the 'average rating'.   So, instead of trying to _store_ the result of that select, simply issue that very same select _when you need to know the average_ - at the time of generating a report that includes average rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefer using a *statement level trigger* rather than a *row level trigger* starting by removing the line `FOR EACH ROW` so as to get new trigger body such as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AvgRate_trig
  AFTER INSERT ON rating
BEGIN
  UPDATE tb_movies t
     SET AvgRating =
         (SELECT AVG(rate)
            FROM rating r
           WHERE t.movieid = r.movieid)
   WHERE movieid IN 
         (SELECT movieid
            FROM rating
           GROUP BY movieid)   
END;
/
```

this way you don't get tabe mutating error.

Comment: thanks, its working.. but i need and explanation why statement level is working? why row level cause mutating?

Comment: Hi @FajarSatyaSanjaya , there's a good comparison [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-row-level-and-statement-level-triggers/)

Answer (score 1):

To address the flawed design, seeing as my original comment seemed to not be understood by the OP, here's a demo of exactly what I'm talking about.  A fundamental rule of data design is that you do not calculate and store a value that can be calculated at run time.  In this particular application, that means you do NOT try to constantly update and store the average of multiple movie ratings.  Instead, calculate it when needed.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> -- -------- create the tables
SQL> create table movies
  2     (    movie_id number not null enable,
  3          movie_title varchar2(30) not null enable,
  4           constraint movies_pk primary key (movie_id)
  5    )
  6  ;

Table created.

SQL> --
SQL> create table ratings
  2     (    rating_id number not null enable,
  3          movie_id number not null enable,
  4          rating_source varchar2(30) not null enable,
  5          movie_rating number not null enable,
  6           constraint ratings_pk primary key (rating_id, movie_id),
  7           constraint ratings_chk1 check (movie_rating in (1,2,3,4,5)) enable,
  8           constraint ratings_fk1 foreign key (movie_id)
  9            references scott.movies (movie_id) on delete cascade enable
 10     )
 11  ;

Table created.

SQL> -- -------- load tables
SQL> insert into movies values (1,'To Kill A Mockingbird');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ratings values (1,1,'Rotten Tomatoes',2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ratings values (2,1,'ImDB',2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ratings values (3,1,'Amazon User',3);

1 row created.

SQL> --
SQL> insert into movies values (2,'Saving Private Ryan');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ratings values (4,2,'Rotten Tomatoes',4);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ratings values (5,2,'ImDB',5);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ratings values (6,2,'Amazon User',5);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> -- -------- Do the query
SQL> select * from movies;

  MOVIE_ID MOVIE_TITLE
---------- ------------------------------
         1 To Kill A Mockingbird
         2 Saving Private Ryan

2 rows selected.

SQL> select * from ratings;

 RATING_ID   MOVIE_ID RATING_SOURCE                  MOVIE_RATING
---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ------------
         1          1 Rotten Tomatoes                           2
         2          1 ImDB                                      2
         3          1 Amazon User                               3
         4          2 Rotten Tomatoes                           4
         5          2 ImDB                                      5
         6          2 Amazon User                               5

6 rows selected.

SQL> select m.movie_title,
  2         avg(r.movie_rating)
  3  from movies m
  4    join ratings r on m.movie_id = r.movie_id
  5  group by m.movie_title
  6  order by m.movie_title
  7  ;

MOVIE_TITLE                    AVG(R.MOVIE_RATING)
------------------------------ -------------------
Saving Private Ryan                     4.66666667
To Kill A Mockingbird                   2.33333333

2 rows selected.

SQL> -- -------- clean up
SQL> drop table ratings purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table movies purge;

Table dropped.
```

That said, the original issue (how to write the trigger) has all the earmarks of a homework problem.  Now, if the assignment was very specifically to write such a trigger, one would hope that the purpose was to teach some coding techniques.  It wouldn't be the first time we've seen a specific homework assignment that was based on a very flawed design, and the design implied by the problem is very flawed.  When I see such, I seriously question the qualifications of the instructor, making an assignment that flies in the face of basic data design principles.  They should have already covered (actually, in a class dedicated to such, and a pre-req to this type of assignment) fundamentals of data design, including but not limited to Data Normalization, First Normal Form, Second Normal Form, and Third Normal Form (Look them up).